# How to set an option as selected based on value in angular from component/html

Tags: html, angular, typescript, crud

I have a select menu of a form which send data to sql DB and fetch back when it is called for editing the same value to be shown in select menu option as selected. Please have a look at my code.

```
<label>State</label>
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "selectedState"  id="statelist" name="statelist" #statelist = "ngModel"  [disabled]="selectedCountry == null || selectedCountry == 0" required ngmodel>
   <option>Select a State</option>
   <option *ngFor="let item of stateListSorted" [ngValue] = "item.name" [selected] = "stateOptions">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**Component**

```
onEditCustomer(customerEdit: Customer): void{
    this.addFormStatus = true;
    this.addBtnStatus = false;
    this.customerEditCall = true;
    this.selectedCustomerEdit = customerEdit;
    this.companyName = this.selectedCustomerEdit.name;
    const country =  this.selectedCustomerEdit.country;
    this.stateOptions = this.selectedCustomerEdit.state;
  }
```

Comment: So you have already the selected item? I would try something like [selected] = "item.id == selecteItem.id"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you need, but you can set the [(ngModel)]="selectedState" to your desired value in your component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmuxxj

Alternatively, to answer your question (but also less readable imo since it's in the HTML), you can put a condition on the "selected" attribute of the  tag

```
<option *ngFor="let item of stateListSorted" [ngValue] = "item.name" [selected] ="item.id === 5">{{item.name}}</option>
```